# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'

Tags: python, libraries, soappy

I am using Python 3 along with SOAPpy Library in conjunction with my code. I keep getting a "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'`" error when trying to run my code. The error is coming from this specific line within the Library:

`from version import __version__`

How do I fix the error?

Comment: What is `version`? Please provide more information. Otherwise the error is clear, there is no such module (or python file) as `version`.

Comment: The version of SOAPpy is 0.12.22, but I don't know where to put that or the syntax to do so.

Comment: If you are simply trying to get SOAPpy's version in code, for most modules, like numpy, you can get its version with `import numpy` and then `numpy.__version__`. Can you try this for SOAPpy?

Answer (score 2):

People usually set the variable `__version__` in a module to make it available to
the world to inspect, it even has a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/)!

I'm not sure about which line you are referring to but there [are many](https://github.com/jeffkit/SOAPpy/search?q=from+version+import+__version__&unscoped_q=from+version+import+__version__) with the same incriminating import in the SOAPpy package.

You can see [here](https://github.com/jeffkit/SOAPpy/blob/develop/SOAPpy/version.py) that the package indeed has a `version` module defining a `__version__` variable. I don't know how are you including this package in your project but I'll explain something about imports, you can read more [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

The incriminating line can have two alternatives

```
from .version import __version__ # relative import

from SOAPpy.version import __version__ # absolute import
```

You could read them as "paths", the first is the version.py file in the current directory, the second is the version.py file in the SOAPpy directory.

They are both fine but sometimes repeating SOAPpy everywhere is too much work.

Let's fix the line to have a relative import

```
diff --git a/SOAPpy/__init__.py b/SOAPpy/__init__.py
index 0e039f8..832a560 100644
--- a/SOAPpy/__init__.py
+++ b/SOAPpy/__init__.py
@@ -1,15 +1,15 @@

 ident = '$Id: __init__.py,v 1.9 2004/01/31 04:20:06 warnes Exp $'
-from version import __version__
+from .version import __version__

-from Client      import *
-from Config      import *
-from Errors      import *
-from NS          import *
-from Parser      import *
-from SOAPBuilder import *
-from Server      import *
-from Types       import *
-from Utilities     import *
+from .Client      import *
+from .Config      import *
+from .Errors      import *
+from .NS          import *
+from .Parser      import *
+from .SOAPBuilder import *
+from .Server      import *
+from .Types       import *
+from .Utilities     import *
 import wstools
 import WSDL
```

And indeed now if I run `python setup.py install` I get a different error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    from SOAPpy.version import __version__
  File "/home/edoput/repo/SOAPpy/SOAPpy/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .Client      import *
  File "/home/edoput/repo/SOAPpy/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 95
    raise IOError, "unsupported SOAP protocol"
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So indeed it might be a problem that this library has not been upgraded to use python3!

Let's use python2 instead, even if [we should not](https://pythonclock.org).

```
virtualenv env --python=python2
source env/bin/activate
python setup.py install
```

And now everything installs correctly, this library has definitely not been updated recently, you can still use it but you have to stick to use python 2.7. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

[SOAPpy](https://github.com/jeffkit/SOAPpy) ([pypy](https://pypi.org/project/SOAPpy/)) seems to be an outdated library meant for python2, which is why some of the code in the library produces these errors. You might have better luck using [Zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/) - a modern SOAP python3 compatible client.